# asp.net show element on one page, and not another

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to add a flash object to the default page of this asp.net website. The pages use a master page to set things like the header, which is where I want this movie. What I'm trying to do is basically

```
[Pseudo Code]

If(current page == default.aspx)
  show (flash object);
Else
  show static header image;

[/End Pseudo Code]
```

I am completely new to asp.net, and have actually googled for solutions, but can't find anything to determine what page you're on. Any help would me much appreciated!

Thanks,
Mike

P.S. I know that most of you will be inclined to offer a suggestion to put in the C# code-behind file, but it has to be inline asp.net because of how we distribute this to clients. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% if( Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath == "~/Default.aspx" ) { %>

<object src="something.swf" type="application/swf"></object>

<% } else { %>

<img src="staticheader.png" alt="header image" />

<% } %>
```

Comment: if( Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath == "~/Default.aspx" )

This isn't returning as true, even if i specifically put http://localhost/CynoiShop/PublicStore/default.aspx into the url.

Comment: @codingbiz I did check the case sensitivity, but it's still not working.

Comment: @David Thank you. This worked. For some reason, although default.aspx is what shows in the url, it's pulling in a different category path. I'm sure that has to do with how the site's hierarchy is set up. Thanks!